# How can one create a time series object with multiple time series?

Tags: r, time-series

How can I convert "A. Raw data" into "B. Time Series Objects" in R so I can perform time series analysis on multiple time series at a time? Please see to sample outputs below.

A.  Raw data

month   item    count
20150101    123456  116
20150201    123456  266
20150301    123456  261
20150401    123456  179
20150501    123456  121
20150601    123456  147
20150701    123456  77
20150801    123456  327
20150901    123456  309
20151001    123456  402
20151101    123456  116
20151201    123456  165
20150101    234567  405
20150201    234567  244
20150301    234567  114
20150401    234567  262
20150501    234567  126
20150601    234567  111
20150701    234567  498
20150801    234567  353
20150901    234567  208
20151001    234567  111
20151101    234567  400
20151201    234567  11
20140101    123456  114
20140201    123456  451
20140301    123456  389
20140401    123456  253
20140501    123456  280
20140601    123456  89
20140701    123456  310
20140801    123456  260
20140901    123456  221
20141001    123456  371
20141101    123456  133
20141201    123456  269
20140101    234567  234
20140201    234567  151
20140301    234567  479
20140401    234567  184
20140501    234567  79
20140601    234567  499
20140701    234567  238
20140801    234567  10
20140901    234567  383
20141001    234567  23
20141101    234567  185
20141201    234567  232

B.  Time Series Objects

```
            Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

123456  2014    114 451 389 253 280 89  310 260 221 371 133 269
123456  2015    116 266 261 179 121 147 77  327 309 402 116 165
234567  2014    234 151 479 184 79  499 238 10  383 23  185 232
234567  2015    405 244 114 262 126 111 498 353 208 111 400 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate form of data for a time series analysis depends, of course, on the analysis you're going to perform and the R functions you'll use to do it.  Having said that, there are several ways to transform your data from your `A` format to `B`. In the code that follows, the `parse_date_time`, `year`, and `month` functions from the `lubridate` package are used to transform your `month` column into an R `POSIX` date object `tmp` then to replace the original `month` column with new `year` and `month` columns.  In particular, this generates the new `month` column as a factor with the months named and ordered in the usual calendar sequence. `spread` from the `tidyr` package uses the unique values in the `month` column to form new columns containing `count` values.  Code follows:

```
  library(lubridate)
  library(tidyr)
# original data in data frame  df_A
  tmp <- parse_date_time(df_A$month, orders="ymd")
  df_B <- cbind( df_A[,-1], year = year(tmp), month=month(tmp, label=TRUE))
  df_B <- spread(df_B, key = month, value = count)
```

The result in df_B is identical to your output data B